# computition with null MS Access

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

My Table name is CAPCON in MS ACess
Fields ae ID,Transaction, AMount,

My query is

```
Select distinct( CapCon.ID),
 (Select sum(amount) from CapCon as c 
    where c.id=CapCon.id 
    and transaction='Deposite') - 
 (Select sum(amount) from CapCon as c 
    where c.id=CapCon.id and transaction='Withdrawal') 
as [Capital Contribution] from CapCOn
```

IF the there is no withdrawal transaction, there is no output in [Capital Contribution] for the corresponding ID

Comment: Hey Ryan, just for future reference, you can format code in a question by indenting it by 4 spaces or putting backticks around it.  The easier you make the question to read, the more likely you will get an answer.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to check for null in your where clause:

```
Select distinct( CapCon.ID),
  (Select sum(amount) from CapCon as c 
     where c.id=CapCon.id 
     and transaction='Deposite') -
  (Select sum(amount) from CapCon as c 
     where c.id=CapCon.id 
     and transaction='Withdrawal' 
     and transaction is not null) 
as [Capital Contribution] from CapCOn
```